# Do apps get notified about a push notification being ignored?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

If a push notification comes thru, and the user taps "close" (to ignore the notification) is the app told about the event?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a one way path, after the user press the close button, its gone forever.